# jQuery preventing form submit when used with $.ajax

Tags: jquery

Here is my jQuery code

```
$("#mappingForm").submit(function () {
    alert("map clicked");

    var mappedBdm = $("#mappedBDMs").val();
    var result = false;

    alert(mappedBdm);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '../../mapMOPBDM',
        data: {
            mappedBdm: mappedBdm
        },
        success: function (html) {
            if (html != "") {
                result = confirm(mappedBdm + " is already assigned to" + html + ". Do you want to continue ?");
                alert(result);
            }
        }
    });

    if (result == false) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

The result shown is false. However the form is still submitted ???

What can be the reason ? What is a solution?

Comment: You'll never get your confirmation since ajax is async... but the form is probably submitting because you haven't defined `e`... `$("#mappingForm").submit(function (e) {`

Comment: That's an answer, not a comment ;-)

Answer (score 0):

e.preventDefault(); you forgot to pass the e param.
use

```
if (result == false) {
        return false;
 }
```

instead

Comment: This would never work as the call is async and this code is hit before result is actually set!

Comment: thanks for your hint.ajax should be set synchronous so as to verify the form

Comment: ...and my second hint is **"never use ajax in synchronous mode"**.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass `e` to your function:

```
$("#mappingForm").submit(function (e) {
```

In addition

```
if (result == false) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

is executed before your ajax success callback

Answer (score 0):

Just return false... `result` is not set before the call exits.

Basically you cannot make the decision based on the ajax call result as that happens later (async).

Comment: And before anyone else suggests converting it to a synchronous call, remember *there be monsters* in synchronous Ajax!